# When is a Doctrine collection effectively hydrated?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In Doctrine Documentation about [filtering associations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections), there's the following code example:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

$group          = $entityManager->find('Group', $groupId);
$userCollection = $group->getUsers();

$criteria = Criteria::create()
    ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("birthday", "1982-02-17"))
    ->orderBy(array("username" => Criteria::ASC))
    ->setFirstResult(0)
    ->setMaxResults(20)
;

$birthdayUsers = $userCollection->matching($criteria);
```

This code is supposed to illustrate the following sentence:

> If the collection has not been loaded from the database yet, the filtering API can work on the SQL level to make optimized access to large collections.

But isn't the collection loaded at the `$group->getUsers()` call? So how can it not be hydrated when the criteria matching is performed?